# Styling disabled <select multiple> controls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm customizing Bootstrap components - both CSS and Javascript - to be theme-able. It is necessary because my themes are reversible; I want to make sure every state of every Bootstrap component can be reversed so that it is accessible and easy to read. I've managed to do this for most components, but I am having trouble styling multiselect controls. I've included some other controls from my test page so that you can see what I am aiming for; I want the text color of the multiselect control to be the same as that of the text, date,  and other controls. If you would like to see the whole page in context, check out my [Bootstrap Test Page](http://www.rapidcityeagles3555.com/BootTest). When I inspect the element in Chrome, it says that the options' color is "graytext" - apparently Chrome's default setting. Why is my CSS not overriding it?

I have another question related to this one; why does Bootstrap enclose the `:disabled` selector in square brackets? i.e. `select[disabled] { ... }`. I've tried both to style the multiselect control.

```css
/* Bootstrap Form Controls */

.form-control {
  background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 95%);
  border-color: hsl(240, 100%, 25%);
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 40%);
}

.form-control:focus {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.form-control[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control,
fieldset[disabled]>select[multiple] .form-control,
textarea:disabled .form-control,
select[disabled] .form-control,
select[multiple] option:disabled .form-control {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 93%);
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control[disabled]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control[disabled]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control[disabled]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control[disabled]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control[disabled]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control[disabled]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control[disabled]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control[disabled]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 40%);
}

.form-control:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 40%);
}

.form-control:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 40%);
}

.form-control:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 40%);
}

.form-control:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 80%);
}

select[multiple].form-control {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.input,
.form-control,
.btn,
.btn+.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-size: 18pt;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Disabled Controls</h3>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="TB_DisabledTextSample">Text Example</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="TB_DisabledTextExample" placeholder="AaBbCcDdEeFfGg" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="TB_DisabledDateSample">Date Example</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" id="TB_DisabledDateExample" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DDL_DisabledMultiSelectSample">Multiple Select Example</label>
        <select multiple id="DDL_DisabledMultiSelectSample" class="form-control input-lg" disabled>
       <option>Coke</option>
              <option>Dr. Pepper</option>
              <option>Mt. Dew</option>
       <option>Pepsi</option>
       <option>Root Beer</option>
       <option>Sprite</option>
      </select>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The selector `select[disabled]` will select all html `select` tags that have the attribute `disabled`

Comment: Cool! Can you combine them? For example `select[multiple][disabled]`? I've tried that to no avail, too. :(

Comment: Yes, you use `select[multiple], select[disabled] { ... }` Note the comma in between the two selectors. If you need to target something that has both the attributes multiple AND disabled then you don't need the comma and you can just use `select[multiple] select[disabled] { ... }` - If someone knows a shorter way please chime in.

Comment: Does reversible in your in this case mean inverted?

Comment: Yes. :D By default the background is light with dark text. When the theme is reversed, the background will be dark and the text will be light.

Comment: CSS has something for this although it's not supported on IE, you may be able to achieve something similar with JS but that's way over my head. Just for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/x4L8kmzj/ - the only differnece between the two blocks is the `.inverted` class

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a total inversion. Please go to http://www.rapidcityeagles3555.com, click on the "Themes" button, and click on your favorite color if you have one. When the page reloads, click the "Themes" button again and click the "Reverse!" checkbox.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, that won't work in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Got it!

The issue is with this line: `select[multiple] option:disabled .form-control {`

This selector translates to "the element with the class `form-control`, who's parent is an `option` with a pseudo-selector of `disabled` who's parent is `select` with the attribute `multiple`".

What you want is "the `select` element with the attribute `multiple`, the pseudo-selector `disabled` and a class of `form-control`. This would become, `select.form-control[multiple]:disabled`.

The addition of the space in your selector indicates that you want to select the element's child. Here's a brief of [everything you can do with CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). The relevant ones are `element,element`, `element element` and `element>element`.

---

To answer your second question, `:disabled` selects elements that are disabled. `[disabled]` selects elements with the attribute `disabled`. However, to disable an element, you *need* to use the `disabled` attribute. Therefore, they are effectively the same. Did I get everything?